# How does one parse XML files?

Tags: c#, xml

Is there a simple method of parsing XML files in C#? If so, what?

Comment: you could use this implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34813985/5784646

Comment: Ok, I reopened this. The duplicate was an XML Reader solution where as this is about parsing XML files. The *posssible duplicate* can be seen in the questions [edit] history ps @GeorgeStocker

Comment: @JeremyThompson One of the reasons why this was a duplicate is the other question has a much better answer. The top answer being a simple "link only" answer is not useful.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the questions are different enough to co-exist and both have **great** answers, plus the accepted ones are using different technologies. That's why I voted we leave this open, I know this accepted one is link only but it is MSDN and was written at a time before that was unacceptable,  hopefully a side effect of reopening is cheering Jon up a bit, *read his profile*. Anyway cheers.

Answer (score 255, accepted):

I'd use [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml) if you're in .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: I tried using this but was unable to figure out how to get something as simple as the value of the identifier of a certain element in my XML  (or how to get an element by identifier, for that matter). In contrast, using XmlDocument I was able to do that with minimal effort.

Comment: I'm with you Kira.  I have yet to grok LINQ to XML, and considering the overhead of LINQ, I've never made the effort to figure it out.  Doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Answer (score 336):

It's very simple. I know these are standard methods, but you can create your own library to deal with that much better.

Here are some examples:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); // Create an XML document object
xmlDoc.Load("yourXMLFile.xml"); // Load the XML document from the specified file

// Get elements
XmlNodeList girlAddress = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("gAddress");
XmlNodeList girlAge = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("gAge"); 
XmlNodeList girlCellPhoneNumber = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("gPhone");

// Display the results
Console.WriteLine("Address: " + girlAddress[0].InnerText);
Console.WriteLine("Age: " + girlAge[0].InnerText);
Console.WriteLine("Phone Number: " + girlCellPhoneNumber[0].InnerText);
```

Also, there are some [other methods](http://www.google.lt/search?hl=lt&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=pLz&q=parse+XML+C%23&btnG=Paie%C5%A1ka&meta=) to work with. For example, [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548). And I think there is no one best method to do this; you always need to choose it by yourself, what is most suitable for you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning XmlDocument, which is much more convenient than serialisation interfaces in some cases. If you are after one specific element, you can access child elements with the indexer: xmlDoc["Root"], and these can be chained: xmlDoc["Root"]["Folder"]["Item"] to dig down the hierarchy (although it's sensible to validate that these elements actually exist)

Comment: `InnerText` here gets the value of that node, concatenated with all values of child nodes - right? Seems like an odd thing to want.

Comment: A programmer with a list of female friends? Shenanigans!

Comment: @E.vanPutten not in this day and age. This is not Revenge of the Nerds

Comment: @DonCheadle If you aren't expecting there to *be* any child nodes, then `InnerText` will just return the node value - which is what I (and probably everyone else reading this question) am parsing the XML to find in the first place.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. XmlDocument is just that much more convenient to use for "basic" situations.

Answer (score 50):

Use a good [XSD Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSD) to create a set of classes with [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) and use an [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to create a object tree out of your XML and vice versa. If you have few restrictions on your model, you could even try to create a direct mapping between you model classes and the XML with the Xml*Attributes.

There is [an introductory article about XML Serialisation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx) on MSDN.

Performance tip: Constructing an `XmlSerializer` is expensive. Keep a reference to your `XmlSerializer` instance if you intend to parse/write multiple XML files.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/xsdtidy.aspx and http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/XsdTidyXSDMappingBeautifier.aspx

Comment: Good example is the "Purchase Order Example" in the middle of this example from microsoft. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx. You avoid having to create a schema -- your c# class is the schema, adorned with C# attributes.

Answer (score 26):

If you're processing a large amount of data (many megabytes) then you want to be using `XmlReader` to stream parse the XML.

Anything else (`XPathNavigator`, `XElement`, `XmlDocument` and even `XmlSerializer` if you keep the full generated object graph) will result in [high memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505075/deciding-on-when-to-use-xmldocument-vs-xmlreader) and also a very slow load time.

Of course, if you need all the data in memory anyway, then you may not have much choice.

Answer (score 18):

Use [`XmlTextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(VS.80).aspx), [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(VS.80).aspx), [`XmlNodeReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader(VS.80).aspx) and the [`System.Xml.XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath(VS.80).aspx) namespace. And ([`XPathNavigator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator(VS.80).aspx), [`XPathDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument(VS.80).aspx), [`XPathExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression(VS.80).aspx), [`XPathnodeIterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator(VS.80).aspx)).

Usually [`XPath`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx) makes reading XML easier, which is what you might be looking for.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 12):

I have just recently been required to work on an application which involved the parsing of an XML document and I agree with Jon Galloway that the LINQ to XML based approach is, in my opinion, the best. I did however have to dig a little to find usable examples, so without further ado, here are a few!

Any comments welcome as this code works but may not be perfect and I would like to learn more about parsing XML for this project!

```
public void ParseXML(string filePath)  
{  
    // create document instance using XML file path
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    // get the namespace to that within of the XML (xmlns="...")
    XElement root = doc.Root;
    XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    // obtain a list of elements with specific tag
    IEnumerable<XElement> elements = from c in doc.Descendants(ns + "exampleTagName") select c;

    // obtain a single element with specific tag (first instance), useful if only expecting one instance of the tag in the target doc
    XElement element = (from c in doc.Descendants(ns + "exampleTagName" select c).First();

    // obtain an element from within an element, same as from doc
    XElement embeddedElement = (from c in element.Descendants(ns + "exampleEmbeddedTagName" select c).First();

    // obtain an attribute from an element
    XAttribute attribute = element.Attribute("exampleAttributeName");
}
```

With these functions I was able to parse any element and any attribute from an XML file no problem at all!

Answer (score 10):

In Addition you can use XPath selector in the following way (easy way to select specific nodes):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");

var found = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//book[@title='Barry Poter']"); // select all Book elements in whole dom, with attribute title with value 'Barry Poter'

// Retrieve your data here or change XML here:
foreach (XmlNode book in nodeList)
{
  book.InnerText="The story began as it was...";
}

Console.WriteLine("Display XML:");
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

[the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using .NET 2.0, try `XmlReader` and its subclasses `XmlTextReader`, and `XmlValidatingReader`. They provide a fast, lightweight (memory usage, etc.), forward-only way to parse an XML file.

If you need [`XPath`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) capabilities, try the `XPathNavigator`. If you need the entire document in memory try `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure whether "best practice for parsing XML" exists. There are numerous technologies suited for different situations. Which way to use depends on the concrete scenario.

You can go with [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML_.28formerly_called_XLINQ.29), [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), [`XPathNavigator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx) or even regular expressions. If you elaborate your needs, I can try to give some suggestions.

Comment: regex for xml. you monster.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the XML using this library `System.Xml.Linq`. Below is the sample code I used to parse a XML file

```
public CatSubCatList GenerateCategoryListFromProductFeedXML()
{
    string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(_xmlFilePath);

    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

    XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(xDoc.ToString());


    List<Category> lstCategory = xElement.Elements("Product").Select(d => new Category
    {
        Code = Convert.ToString(d.Element("CategoryCode").Value),
        CategoryPath = d.Element("CategoryPath").Value,
        Name = GetCateOrSubCategory(d.Element("CategoryPath").Value, 0), // Category
        SubCategoryName = GetCateOrSubCategory(d.Element("CategoryPath").Value, 1) // Sub Category
    }).GroupBy(x => new { x.Code, x.SubCategoryName }).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

    CatSubCatList catSubCatList = GetFinalCategoryListFromXML(lstCategory);

    return catSubCatList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer) to serialize and deserialize.

**Instalation**
You can install ExtendedXmlSerializer from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) or run the following command:

```
Install-Package ExtendedXmlSerializer
```

**Serialization:**

```
ExtendedXmlSerializer serializer = new ExtendedXmlSerializer();
var obj = new Message();
var xml = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

**Deserialization**

```
var obj2 = serializer.Deserialize<Message>(xml);
```

**Standard XML Serializer in .NET is very limited.**

- Does not support serialization of class with circular reference or class with interface property,
- Does not support Dictionaries,
- There is no mechanism for reading the old version of XML,
- If you want create custom serializer, your class must inherit from IXmlSerializable. This means that your class will not be a POCO class,
- Does not support IoC.

**ExtendedXmlSerializer can do this and much more.**

ExtendedXmlSerializer support **.NET 4.5** or higher and **.NET Core**. You can integrate it with WebApi and AspCore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmlDocument and for manipulating or retrieve data from attributes you can Linq to XML classes.