# Parse XML document in C#

Tags: c#, xml

**Duplicate:** This is a duplicate of [Best practices to parse xml files with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files-with-c) and many others (see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+parse+xml). Please close it and do not answer.

---

How do you parse XML document from bottom up in C#?

For Example :

```
<Employee>
   <Name> Test </name>
   <ID> 123 </ID>
<Employee>
<Company>
    <Name>ABC</company>
    <Email>test@ABC.com</Email>
 </company>
```

Like these there are many nodes..I need to start parsing from bottom up like..first parse `<company>` and then  and so on..How doi go about this in C# ?

Comment: checkout the System.Xml Namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: You can use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class. It takes your class and can read/write it to XML files really easily.

Comment: I like Linq's [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Answer (score 63):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Path\To\Xml\File.xml");
```

Or alternatively if you have the XML in a string use the `LoadXml` method.

Once you have it loaded, you can use `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` to query specific values, for example:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Company/Email/text()");
// node.Value contains "test@ABC.com"
```

Finally, note that your XML is invalid as it doesn't contain a single root node. It must be something like this:

```
<Data>
    <Employee>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <ID>123</ID>
    </Employee>
    <Company>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <Email>test@ABC.com</Email>
    </Company>
</Data>
```