# REST communication with WPF

Tags: wpf, rest, chat

I am trying to write a Help Desk Application.

The problem I am facing is how to put up a chat like communication between the REST service and my application. I am confused and a rookie as well.

All I know is GET(URI) and POST(URI) methods from which I get the XML.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: did you try to add a service reference in VS ? errors ?

Comment: nope.. i am just requesting. Adding service was giving me errors about xmlns schema which i have no idea about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is probably not the best architectural style to build a chat application.  You should look at protocols like XMPP and AMQP.  They are much more suited to this two-way communication model.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to write a [REST client](http://jamescrisp.org/2008/08/08/simple-rest-client/) in C#/.NET

**WPF** has nothing to do with your question. The post/get uri's will get you the *data* that needs to be *presented*. How it is presented is what you deal with using **WPF**, but the **REST** part itself is independent of any language/platform.

Comment: i am able to get the xml from the Get(URI), but the problem is how to continously getting data and update the TextBlock for the chat.

Comment: For that you need to tell us what API are you using. That should probably be a part of the API's documentation.

Comment: Ozair bhai, i am just using methods like xml.Load(URI) and then trying to parse the incoming xml. Not using any designed API.

Comment: I just want to get the responses from the xml and display them in a TextBlock. I am able to do polling on the server for data i cant understand how to continously update the TextBlock and create a chat like environment

Comment: ok, look at this SO thread, I am sure there are many other related threads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238528/parse-xml-document-in-c