# How can I fill variables with xml node values from a xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file that looks like this:

```
            <item>
                  <title>Lore ipsum etc </title>
                  <description>lorem ipsum etc etc</description>
                  <link>http://url.com</link>
                  <guid isPermaLink="false">http://url.com</guid>
                  <pubDate>Sat, 27 Apr 2013 14:56:50 GMT</pubDate>
                  <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://url.com/media/images/67275000/jpg/_67275945_017846423.jpg" />
          <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://http://url.com/media/images/67276000/jpg/_67276200_017846423.jpg" />
           </item>
        <item>
              <title>Lore ipsum etc </title>
              <description>lorem ipsum etc etc</description>
              <link>http://url.com</link>
              <guid isPermaLink="false">http://url.com</guid>
              <pubDate>Sat, 28 Apr 2013 14:56:50 GMT</pubDate>
 <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://url.com/media/images/67275000/jpg/_67275945_017846423.jpg" />
      <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://http://url.com/media/images/67276000/jpg/_67276200_017846423.jpg" />
       </item>
```

the list have around 50 items.

How can I give my variables the value that is  inside `<title>`, `<description>`, `<link>` and `<PubDate>`.

I have done this so far:

```
url = "http://url.com/file.xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I would look into linq and xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you try to parse an RSS feed. you can use [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) for this.

But anyway, it is  a simple xml and you can use Linq To Xml

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(url);
var items = xdoc.Descendants("item")
            .Select(item => new
            {
                Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                description = item.Element("description").Value,
                Link = item.Element("link").Value
            })
            .ToList();
```

PS: You haven't posted the complete xml, (for ex, no root element) you may still have issues with *Xml namespaces*.

Comment: Inside the <item> I have <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://url.com/blaba.jpg" /> How can I fill the img url this one also?

Comment: @Obsivus As i said in the answer `you may still have issues with Xml namespaces`. Without seeing your full xml, It is not possible to give an answer.

Comment: I tried the syndicationfeed it worked very good no issues at all but there is no property for images

Comment: @Obsivus Because they are provider-dependent properties. You may need to use Linq To Xml to get these properties.

Comment: I see, I tried the linq to xml it worked also but I cant seem to get the second thumbnail media image to get filled :( Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I updated my code you can see it on the question, I want the last thumbail image url not the first one

Comment: You should use `XNameSpace`. the part of xml you posted is not enough. There must be a declaration for `media` somewhere at the beginning of your xml.

Comment: @Obsivus I am trying to give an answer with limited informations you posts. But, sorry, I am not willing to continue this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to XML (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is a good start.

And some other examples:

[How does one parse XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

[Reading data from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119806/c-sharp-reading-data-from-xml)

[Parse XML document in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238528/parse-xml-document-in-c-sharp?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize xml try this approach: http://undefinedvalue.com/2011/11/22/deserializing-objects-xml-c