# XML parsing differences in .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How has XML parsing in .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0 evolved? There are many different samples out there.

We need to read/write mid to big size XML files and want to use the most efficient way in .NET Framework 4.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have a look at specific answers here:
[Deciding on when to use XmlDocument vs XmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505075/deciding-on-when-to-use-xmldocument-vs-xmlreader)

As you can see it is not only a question of performance but memory usage as well. see the experts' anwers with runtimes in yellow