# PDF files with XML files attached

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

HI All,

I have a PDF file with a xml attached, i need to parse the xml file. Does anyone knows how i do that? 
I´m using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this blog post](http://studentclub.ro/lucians_weblog/archive/2007/03/22/read-from-a-pdf-file-using-c.aspx) describing how read from a PDF file using C# is what you want.

This is the example he gives of grabbing text from the PDF:

```
using System;
using org.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.pdfbox.util;

namespace PDFReader
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("lopreacamasa.pdf");
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        Console.Write(pdfStripper.getText(doc));
    }
}
}
```

[Here](http://jadn.co.uk/w/ReadPdfUsingCsharp.htm) is what looks like an exhaustive and highly organized list of how to read PDFs with C#.

If what you need is some form of embedded meta data, as Mark suggested, I'm sure it's also possible with the to fetch using the tools I've linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx#xlinqoverview_topic3) as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files-with-c) question.

Comment: HI,
The problem is not parse the xml, but access the xml inside the pdf. Do you know how i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you describe the situation a little more?  Where exactly is the XML?

Comment: I think the xml file is embedded in the pdf document.
Tanks

Answer (score 0):

PDF files can have a meta data information object or is it an XML file embedded as an object?

Comment: The XML file is embedded as an object.
Thanks