# How to parse XML?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

This is the response I'll be getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
        <image_hash>cxmHM</image_hash>
        <delete_hash>NNy6VNpiAA</delete_hash>
        <original_image>http://imgur.com/cxmHM.png</original_image>
        <large_thumbnail>http://imgur.com/cxmHMl.png</large_thumbnail>
        <small_thumbnail>http://imgur.com/cxmHMl.png</small_thumbnail>
        <imgur_page>http://imgur.com/cxmHM</imgur_page>
        <delete_page>http://imgur.com/delete/NNy6VNpiAA</delete_page>
</rsp>
```

How can I extract the value of each tag?

```
XDocument response = new XDocument(w.UploadValues("http://imgur.com/api/upload.xml", values));
string originalImage = 'do the extraction here';
string imgurPage = 'the same';
UploadedImage image = new UploadedImage();
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately it's pretty simple:

```
string originalImage = (string) response.Root.Element("original_image");
string imgurPage = (string) response.Root.Element("imgur_page");
// etc
```

That's assuming your `XDocument` constructor call is correct... without knowing what `w.UploadValues` does, that's hard to say.

LINQ to XML makes querying very easy - let us know if you have anything more complicated.

Note that I've used a cast to string instead of taking the `Value` property or anything like that. That means if the `<original_image>` element is missing, `originalImage` will be null rather than an exception being thrown. You *may* prefer the exception, depending on your exact situation.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. How could I retrive the 'stat' attribute of the root tag?

Comment: @Sergio: Well, you could call `response.Root.Attribute("stat").Remove()` - but if you're just parsing data from it, why bother?

Comment: The stat gives me information whether or not the upload was correct. :p

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework has an excellent, simple to use XML Parser built right in. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(VS.95).aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

One way is the use the .net [xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) to create a wrapper class for the rsp xml block you have stated in your question.  Once you have the class created you can simply use the following code block to searealize the xml into an object you can use directly in your code.  Of course there is always [Xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), or linq as Jon stated as options as well if you prefer to load the xml into and xmldocument object as you have done above.

```
    public static rsm GetRsmObject(string xmlString)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rsm));
        rsm result = null;

        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            result = (rsm)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It's not in XmlDocument - it's in XDocument, which makes this sort of thing really trivial. Personally I wouldn't mess with XmlSerializer for this.

Comment: I love XmlSerializer, but I do see that XDocument and linq make this really trivial.