# Read XML with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file that looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <Ribbon>
      <Tab Text="Tab1">
        <Grupi Text="Grupi1">
          <Buttoni Moduli="Appdec.Simea.Modulet.DepartamentetM.dll" />
        </Grupi>
        <Grupi Text="Grupi2" />
      </Tab>
      <Tab Text="Tab2">
        <Grupi Text="Grupi1">
          <Buttoni Moduli="Appdec.Simea.Modulet.DhomatM.dll" />
        </Grupi>
        <Grupi Text="Grupi2">
          <Buttoni Moduli="Appdec.Simea.Modulet.KategoriteEArtikujveM.dll" />
          <Buttoni Moduli="Appdec.Simea.Modulet.KategoriteEArtikujveM.dll" />
        </Grupi>
      </Tab>
    </Ribbon>
```

How to iterate throught each element and print the value

Comment: your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices to parse xml files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files)

Comment: sorry folks I didn't mean to post the question like this.

Comment: Consider using punctuation. [,.!?'] it makes your questions much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top sample in this article, [Accessing Attributes in the DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk61a712.aspx), shows how to retrieve the attributes and their values for an XML snippet containing only one `Element`. If you combine that with the [ChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) property of the [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) class, you could iterate first through all the elements and then through all the attributes of each element.