# How I can read and excute a big xml file?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

my code gives me error : "'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1."

```
    string FileName = "20110606 100419 ServerForShop 1.xml";
    string root = Server.MapPath("~/Include/Xml Files/Patch/");       

    var custs = from c in XElement.Load(root + FileName).Elements("Update")
            select c;
```

I want to read and execute command a big xml file it is about 350MB how I can read it ? here is my xml file structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Update>
  <Object Name="Good">
    <Insert Table="Good">
      <Field Name="GoodCode" Value="1" Type="Integer" />
      <Field Name="GoodUserCode" Value="" Type="String" />
      .
      .
      .
    </Insert>
  </Object>
  </Update>
```

Comment: It sounds like your XML file is actually invalid - it may be encoded in UTF-16, despite its *claim* to be in UTF-8.

Comment: You cannot **execute** an XML file.... XML is data - not executable code....

Comment: use a hexdump program and see if http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet is correct

Comment: @marc_s: If your XML encodes processing instructions, you can execute it -- just like any other text-based programming language.

Comment: @Gabe: OK, but that seems like a rather rare edge-case - not the average typical XML usage....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking here for some samples http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548
and perhaps here [How does one parse XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files)