# Get the data between tags in a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I want to get the data between the `<lat>` and `<lng>` tags in the following XML:

```xml
<viewport>
 <southwest>
  <lat>41.7450495</lat>
  <lng>-87.8859170</lng>
 </southwest>
</viewport>
```

which is part of a bigger XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>locality</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Chicago, IL, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Chicago</long_name>
   <short_name>Chicago</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Cook</long_name>
   <short_name>Cook</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Illinois</long_name>
   <short_name>IL</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>41.8781136</lat>
    <lng>-87.6297982</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>41.7450495</lat>
     <lng>-87.8859170</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>42.0109012</lat>
     <lng>-87.3736794</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>41.6443350</lat>
     <lng>-87.9402669</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>42.0231310</lat>
     <lng>-87.5236609</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Right now, I'm trying to use this code to parse it:

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+address+"&sensor=false";
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string result = client.DownloadString(url);

var element = XElement.Parse(result);
var lat = (double)element.Element("lat");
var lng = (double)element.Element("lng");
```

but it isn't working, element is `null`.  How can I do this?

Comment: The obligatory answer to this sort of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why do you want to use regex to read what appears to be well-formed XML?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something more along the lines of how to parse an xml file? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files ?

Comment: @Gabi: bobince is really amazing! :) @karthik: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. Have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Comment: @naveen. Sure regex (due to being regular and hence the product of finite automaton) are not touring complete and hence not apt to parse whole XML files. Nevertheless if you only want to excerpt some value between two wellknown tags no matter where they appear, regex will surely do the trick. Obviously you should parse XML with an XML parser, but OP's question is legit.

Comment: @Hyperboreous: regex will surely do the trick. but should regex do something that xml parser can do? take a look at jeffs solution and your solution. which strikes you as a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Regexes are *not* regular any more. Some current regex implementations even offer recursive pattern matching, nearly all of them have backreferences etc. Yes, they are still not Turing (!) complete (although I'm not convinced that an XML parser needs to be), and there definitely are better tools for parsing XML etc., but regular expressions have come a long way from their old days.

Comment: @naveen. I already pointed out that the cleaner solution for parsing XML is an XML parser. But as OP asked for a regex, I provided a regex.

Comment: @Tim Sure, many so called "regex" - likes perl's for instance - have recursion and backreferencing and a lot more. But as you already pointed out: they are not regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression, parse it.  This uses LINQ to XML.

This should work for you:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
var sw = doc.Descendants("viewport").Elements("southwest").SingleOrDefault();
if (sw != null)
{
    var lat = (double)sw.Element("lat");
    var lng = (double)sw.Element("lng");
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: To go even more "by the book" you could use XmlConvert.ToDouble instead of casting.

Comment: `WebClient client = new WebClient();
            
string result = client.DownloadString(url);
            
var element = XElement.Parse(result);
var lat = (double)element.Element("lat");
var lng = (double)element.Element("lng");`

This is my code. I am getting error as value cannot be null for 'element'. the first attribute of element is null but it is reading the xml correctly.

Comment: @karthik. paste your full correct xml by editing the question.

Comment: @naveen : the complete xml is provided in the question. Here I want any one lat and lng tag values.

Comment: @karthik: It's unclear which elements you want here now.  Do you want the elements under the `viewport` element or the `bounds` element?

Comment: @Jeff: yes. its the only one. @karthik: if you have provided all these infos you could have gotten your answer earlier :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
.*<lat>([^<]*)</lat>.*<lng>([^<]*)</lng>.*
```

with DOTALL (s) flag and the capturing groups return the latitude and longitude.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is no longer about regular expressions anymore.

Comment: As I did not know about the XML parse I have asked the solution in regular exression. But this regular exression worked fine and gave me the solution what exactly I want. thanks Hyperboreus.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works fine....

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string result = client.DownloadString(url);
var element = XElement.Parse(result);
var lat = element.Descendants("lat").First();
var lng = element.Descendants("lng").First();
```