# How do I read XML files and base settings in my C# program off the XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best practices to parse xml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files)
>   [How do I read the contents of an XML element using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879805/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-an-xml-element-using-c)

I'm trying to make a program in C# that can read an XML file, and search for specific elements. It can then read what's contained in said element, and use it in the program.

How do I read an XML file like that?

Comment: Not a double post nor duplicate so please leave.