# How do I read the contents of an XML element using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices to parse xml files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files)

I want to be able to search an XML document for a specific element, then take all that is in the element and store each new line within the element into a string array using C#. How would I do that?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml+c%23.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using LINQ to XML or the classic `System.Xml` interface?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879670/how-do-i-read-xml-files-and-base-settings-in-my-c-program-off-the-xml-file

Comment: As was suggested in your previous question: stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml+c%23

Comment: I think you should clarify whether contents here are elements bs text

Comment: -1 for asking the same question twice.

Comment: @Jacob: see the [faq]. Your comment has been flagged.

Comment: @Jacob: You should learn how to write good questions here.

Comment: @Jacob also insulting people who are trying to help you is not the best thing to do if you want an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml"));
var elm = from element in xdoc.Descendants("element")
           select new { 
               attribute = element.Attribute("attribute").Value,
           };
```

Comment: How do I access XDocument? It says "The type or namespace name 'XDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" How can I fix that error?

Comment: @Jacob: using system.xml.linq it's linq to xml.

Answer (score 1):

...alternatively, you could use the pre-existing settings framework in Visual Studio. It won't suit a custom XML file, but if the idea is to read/write application settings from/to an XML file, it does most of the hard work for you. It will select a suitable location for such a file, auto-generate code such that it's very easy to interact with settings and it abstracts away the file IO side of things. Definitely worth a peek to check that you're not re-inventing it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9db58th.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's some brain compiled pseudo code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myDoc.xml");
XmlNodeList list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("My Element");
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
    //process node
```