# Xml Deserialization from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

i have got a xml file and i want make class or classes from xml file.How can i make?
Sample Xml File

```
<transfer>
<sourceGLN>8680001080359</sourceGLN>
<destinationGLN>8680001404780</destinationGLN>
<actionType>S</actionType>
<shipTo></shipTo>
<documentNumber>265561</documentNumber>
<documentDate>2012-06-07</documentDate>
<note></note>
<version>1.4</version>
<carrier carrierLabel="1">
<productList GTIN="08699516355616" lotNumber="CH4257" expirationDate="2015-03-31">
<serialNumber>00000011214455</serialNumber>
<serialNumber>00000011214456</serialNumber>
<serialNumber>00000011214457</serialNumber>
<serialNumber>00000011214458</serialNumber>
<serialNumber>00000011214459</serialNumber>
<serialNumber>00000011214460</serialNumber>
</productList>
</transfer>
```

Thanks...

Comment: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, and depending on what you would want exactly you can do different ways.

Easiest probably is to use `LINQ to XML` of read your file with an `XmlDocument` object

Also check out:
[How does one parse XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files)

Answer (score 0):

[Look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document), or simply google it...