# How to find value within dynamic string using Regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Here is an example of the string that can be dynamically build.

```
{Static String} <a href="{Dynamic Value}"><b>{Dynamic Value 2}</b></a>

example of static text <a href="http://www.exampleurl.com">example value</a>
```

How with in C# using Regex to find {Dynamic Value 2} or example value?

Comment: Perhaps you should use an [xml parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files) rather than regex?

Comment: So, which bit is the string? all of it?

Comment: All of it, but I need to find value

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private string ExtractString(string sourceString)
{
    // (?<=string) is positive look-behind where you search for string before the match.
    // .* is all characters in between.
    // (?=string) is positive look-ahead where you search for string after the match.
    string pattern = "(?<=<a.*?>).*(?=</a)";
    Match match = Regex.Match(sourceString, pattern);
    return match.Value;
}
```

Of course, you should be implementing some kind of exception handling mechanism.

Note that this will return

```
<b>{Dynamic Value 2}</b>
```

if parsing

```
<a href="{Dynamic Value}"><b>{Dynamic Value 2}</b></a>
```

You can process the string further with other regex patterns if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will get your desired result.

```
string Actualstring = "{static string}<a href='{Dynamic Value}'><b>{Dynamic Value 2}</b></a>"  string prevSplitBy = {static string};string desiredstring="";
     string FirstSplitBy = "<b>";
                    string SecondSplitBy = "</b>";
                    Regex regexprevSplit = new Regex(prevSplitBy );Regex regexFirstSplit = new Regex(FirstSplitBy);
                    Regex regexSecondSplit = new Regex(SecondSplitBy);
                  string[] StringprevSplit = regexprevSplit.Split(Actualstring );string[] StringFirstSplit = regexFirstSplit.Split(StringprevSplit[1] );
                    string[] StringSecondSplit = regexSecondSplit.Split(StringFirstSplit[1]); if(StringSecondSplit!=null){ for(int i=0 ; i <StringSecondSplit.count-1;i++)desiredstring=desiredstring+StringSecondSplit[i] }
```

`desiredstring` will have your desired string.

Comment: In my example you can see static and dynamic content. So I cannot split by "<b>" because it can be multiple occurrences. I need to include static value too.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Raw parsing. Not recommended.

```
{Static String} <a href="{Dynamic Value}"><b>{Dynamic Value 2}</b></a>
```

is well parsed with something like

```
Regex parser = new Regex(
 @"*?\<a href\=\""(?<value1>[^\""]*)\""\>\<b\>(?<value2>[^\<]*)\<\/b\>\<\/a\>");
```

---

### Option 2: XML parsing. Recommended.

```
XElement el = XElement.Parse("<a>your long html string to parse</a>").Element("a");
string v1 = el.Attribute("href").Value;
string v2 = el.Element("b").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

People on stackoverflow seem to be suggesting http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ for parsing html and extracting values from it. It is more fault tolerant than using a regex. If using a regex you will have to change the regex if anything is changed in the strings you search.