# how to replace string pattern in c#

Tags: c#, xml

My c# program retrieves an xml data column from my db containing a path to a text file as follwows

```
<path>
  <path name="myfile" url="/test/dir/YUUHGGGVFY/grgrggr.text" />
</path>
```

So the above is stored in a string variable `name = pathstring`

How can I format the above string to only extract the `"/test/dir/YUUHGGGVFY/grgrggr.text"` portion ?

The other sections of the string will always be the same:

so `pathstring = "/test/dir/YUUHGGGVFY/grgrggr.text"` portion ?

Comment: See this SO question: [Best practices to parse xml files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/best-practices-to-parse-xml-files)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to parse your string and get `url` attribute from `path`

```
string xml = 
  @"<path>
       <path name=""myfile"" url=""/test/dir/YUUHGGGVFY/grgrggr.text"" />
    </path>";
XElement pathElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var pathString = (string)pathElement.Element("path").Attribute("url");
```

Comment: @sixlettervariables thanks I was thinking that I missed something and yes, it was referencing `Root` element

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LINQ2XML. I'll just provide you with a working solution for that particular use case:

```
string path = 
  @"<path>
      <path name=""myfile"" url=""/test/dir/YUUHGGGVFY/grgrggr.text"" />
    </path>";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(path);
var pathString = (string)xdoc.Element("path").Element("path").Attribute("url");
```