# Take HTML Table and put into custom List

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I have an html table I need to query, get the contents and then act on that.
this the table

```
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th>Usage</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>1.0.1.1</td>
                    <td>86</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>1.0.0.1</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>1.0.1.0</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>1.0.0.0</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>

          </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm getting that by passing the WebResponse through a regex expression.

What is the best way to get this into some data structure in C# so that I can query on the Version and Usage.. Baically have a List of class Foo.

Foo()
{
Version {get; set;}
Usage {get; set;}
}

Along those lines.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Parsing like xml might work. See XmlDocument

Comment: "What is the best way" is not a good question for SO. Show what you've tried and we can help you if it's not working

Comment: I don't know how to do it, so I haven't tried anything.  I would have said if the method I was trying didn't work.

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files

Answer (score 2):

The best tool I've found for parsing HTML is the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library. It is a fairly easy to use library, and will handle improperly formatted markup fairly well. You'll have to do the footwork of getting the data out from the library and into your own structures, but it'll make it easy for getting at the data.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that.