# Filling a ViewList from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, parameters, linq-to-xml

Please will some-one explain to me how I go about creating the following program with C#? Alternatively, a link to an explanation about doing this would be appreciated. I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documents>
  <document id="konsoliduota-saskaita">
    <header>
      <parameter id="kliento-pavadinimas">UAB "ALVORA"</parameter>
      <parameter id="adresas1">VISORIŲ 33</parameter>
      <parameter id="adresas2">VILNIUS</parameter>
      <parameter id="adresas3">08300</parameter>
      <parameter id="adresas4"/>
      <parameter id="kliento-numeris">047539</parameter>
      <parameter id="dokumento-numeris">20077</parameter>
      <parameter id="dokumento-data">2013 04 01</parameter>
      <parameter id="mokejimo-terminas">2013 05 01</parameter>
      <parameter id="imones-kodas">1220</parameter>
      <parameter id="pvm-moketojo-kodas">LT220</parameter>
      <parameter id="viso-uz-paslaugas-be-pvm">10.00</parameter>
      <parameter id="viso-suma-be-pvm">194.36</parameter>
      <parameter id="viso-suma-su-pvm">192.11</parameter>
      <parameter id="periodas">2013 03 01-2013 03 31</parameter>
    </header>
  </document>
</documents>
```

I'm aiming to do this:

---

In ViewList, add an item (text: `UAB "ALVORA"`), from the parameter with ID `kliento-pavadinimas`. All other parameters' text should go to ViewList item's subitem(s).

---

The following image shows what I'm aiming to achieve :
http://s10.postimg.org/ofgrtgnbt/form.jpg

Comment: Please can your question make sense?

Comment: Have you tried anything? (Hint: See Linq to Xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [How does one parse XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/efcb9fe3-8d1a-47b0-a35e-8415ac1a93bd/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7718/Using-XML-in-C-in-the-simplest-way ? At least one of those should prove useful.

Comment: Why has my answer been voted down?