# How to load XML items to List of items

Tags: c#, xml

I'd need to load items from XML to a `List<T>`.Could you please give me an advice how to do that in c# class? I have a `List<Item> lItems = new List<Item>();`
and my XML file looks like this:

```
<Items>
   <Item>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Title>aaa</Title>>
      <ImageUrl>"Images/aaa.gif"</ImageUrl>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Title>bbb</Title>
      <ImageUrl>"Images/bbb.jpg"</ImageUrl>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Title>ccc</Title>
      <ImageUrl>"Images/ccc.jpg"</ImageUrl>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

Comment: Before we start giving ideas of how you might do it, what have you tried? As a hint, LINQ to XML makes this fairly easy.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/55828/1457882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items = XDocument.Load(filename)
            .Descendants("Item")
            .Select(i => new Item
            {
                Id = (int)i.Element("Id"),
                Title = (string)i.Element("Title"),
                ImageUrl = (string)i.Element("ImageUrl"),
            })
            .ToList();
```