# Creating a console application displaying XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I need help in creating a console application, where I have to get a list of items from a XML document using a server, remote and client. I have already created a XML document

XML document looks like this:

```
<clothing>
   <pants>Jeans</pants>
   <shirt>T-Shirt</shirt>
   <shoes>Boots</shoes>
</clothing>
```

Now my question is where do I go from here? I understand the basics but don't know how to proceed with this, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: MSDN contains some notes on how to [start reading Xml documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056.aspx). Also, there is an extensive [tutorial on C# Corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx) on the topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/55828/62576

Comment: @tomfanning - its my pre practical so basically to practise before I can do my practical test.

Comment: @tnw not asking how to do the rest of it, just asking where do I go from here? I just need a starting point to work from.

Comment: @Yi-NainChen Like I said, look up examples and documentation. Perhaps Google [C# parse xml](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+parse+xml&aq=f&oq=c%23+parse+xml&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j60l3j61.2258j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tips on creating a console application, see [How to: Create a C# Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). To read an XML file, look into [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx). There are samples in the `XmlDocument` documentation that will show you how to get individual elements and attributes from the document.

For client/server communications, it's hard to say. Probably you want something like [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx).

That should at least get you a starting place.