# Reading XML file into memory and searching it

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have a given XML file that I need to process.  For the sake of argument, let's say I've already loaded it in as a string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<GROUP ID="_group_id" ORDERINFO="00000" TITLE="Group 1">
  <GROUP ID="_group_id_2" TITLE="Group 2">
    <LO ID="_id_code1" LANG="enUS" TYPE="_cust" TITLE="Title 1" /> 
    <LO ID="_id_code2" LANG="enUS" TYPE="_cust" TITLE="Title 2" /> 
  </GROUP>
  <GROUP ID="_group_id_3" TITLE="Group 3">
    <LO ID="_id_code1" LANG="enUS" TYPE="_cust" TITLE="Title 1" /> 
    <LO ID="_id_code2" LANG="enUS" TYPE="_cust" TITLE="Title 2" /> 
  </GROUP>
</GROUP>
```

There can be many LOs and many GROUPs in a given XML file.  I've been trying various methods with no luck.  I need something that will find the matching LO by ID to a given string and then allow me to retrieve the corresponding TYPE and TITLE into strings so that I may use them for processing.

I tried reading the file into an XmlDocument but once loaded I could not figure out how to find the appropriate elements.

Sorry for post prior to edit - some text got cut off

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry, neglected to add all text.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files

Comment: You didn't already tried [SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx) with an argument like `//LO[@ID="yourcode"]`

Comment: I like LINQ to XML (XDocument) myself.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) to parse the Xml.

Here is an example with `XDocument`:

Data class:

```
public class Lo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(data);

var value = "_id_code1";

IEnumerable<Lo> result = 
    document.XPathSelectElements(".//LO")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value == value)
            .Select(x =>
                new Lo
                {
                    Id = x.Attribute("ID").Value,
                    Lang = x.Attribute("LANG").Value,
                    Type = x.Attribute("TYPE").Value,
                    Title = x.Attribute("TITLE").Value
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

When loaded into a XmlDocument, you can use XPath to locate notes.

E.g:

```
XmlNode group = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/GROUP/GROUP[@ID='_group_id_2']");
```

Or:

```
XmlNodeList groups = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/GROUP/GROUP");
foreach(XmlNode group in groups)
{
    string id = group.Attributes["ID"].Value;

}
```

It is very easy.  For a more complete walk through you should search the internet.

Comment: I've been doing some researching on how to do this using XPath like you suggested, as I would prefer to use this as I may be constrained to .net 2.0 in this case.  My issue is that I don't know how many GROUPs there may or may not be.. so I have tried writing a statement that skips all of the group stuff, but I get a null result every time:  XmlNode group = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//LO[ID=" + strcourseID + "]"); where strcourseID is the course ID I have stored in a string.

Comment: Got it sorted out.  I used SelectSingleNode("//LO[@ID=\"" + strcourseID + "\"]"); and that solved the problem.  Finicky syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation:

- [Overview of XML in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfkahe27.aspx).
- [XML Processing Options in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x4kfk8w.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to cast `XAtribute` to string, then access its `Value` property (if some attribute not found, you will get `null` instead of exception). Also query syntax is more compact here

```
string id = "_id_code1";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var query = from lo in xdoc.Descendants("LO")
            where (string)lo.Attribute("ID") == id
            select new {
                Id = (string)lo.Attribute("ID"),
                Language = (string)lo.Attribute("LANG"),
                Type = (string)lo.Attribute("TYPE"),
                Title = (string)lo.Attribute("TITLE")
            };
```

This query will return sequence of anonymous objects with properties Id, Language, Type, Title. You can enumerate them with `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

I did small test application for this, I included your xml as the string.

```
            var xmlMessage = @"keep your xml here, I removed due to formatting";
        var matchedElements = XDocument.Parse(xmlMessage).Descendants().Where(el => el.Name == "LO" && el.Attribute("ID").Value == "_id_code1");
        foreach (var el in matchedElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ElementName : {0}\nID = {1}\nLANG = {2}\nTYPE = {3}\nTITLE = {4}\n"
                , el.Name.LocalName, el.Attribute("ID").Value, el.Attribute("LANG").Value, el.Attribute("TYPE").Value, el.Attribute("TITLE").Value);

         }
```

This would help you to fetch all LO elements having the ID "_id_code" irrespective of the GROUP element. 
If you need to consider the group, replace the second line code with this:

```
var matchedElements = XDocument.Parse(xmlMessage).Descendants().Where(el => el.Parent != null && el.Parent.Attribute("ID").Value == "_group_id_2" && el.Name == "LO" && el.Attribute("ID").Value == "_id_code1");
```

Here, I'm checking for the "_group_id_2", you can replace with your group id.

The required namespaces:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```