# Sending xml via post with WCF but getting error 415

Tags: wcf

I built a wcf service according to this post of stackoverflow: [How to send xml via post with wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906692/how-to-send-xml-via-post-with-wcf)  but I am getting this error :

> The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message
>   because the content type 'application/xml' was not the expected type
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..

I think there is somethimg wrong with my Web.config I am posting it here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="BridgeService.BridgeData" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"   contract="BridgeService.IBridgeData" behaviorConfiguration="MyEndpointBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:10912/Vishi/BridgeService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyEndpointBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is Interface:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IBridgeData
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "InsertData",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string InsertData(transport_xml transport_xml);
}
```

And calling is same like the referenced post of Stackoverflow. please help me. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Change your Binding to **webHttpBinding**.

```
binding="basicHttpBinding"
```

And make sure that when you make request, don't forget to add `Content-Type` like:

```
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

to use a ***Rest*** behavior you must have ***webHttpBinding***. Try changing that.