# XML StreamReader deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I receive xml file like this. I need to convert this xml to an object.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <PrepaidBill>
      <AccountDetails FCName="" TariffName="" Area="1000" SLDG="5000" SLEB="5000" ToDate="12/31/2013" FromDate="12/1/2013" Address="1st Cross, 26th Main, 9th block, Jayanagar" MeterNumber="DCPLCMTRXXX80001" ConsumerName="Pravin Nidoni"/>
    </PrepaidBill>
```

How to deserialize it? I have created a class for XML like

```
namespace ConvertXMLtoObject
{
        [XmlRoot("PrepaidBill")]
        public class BOPrepaidBill
        {
            public AccountDetails AccountDetails { get; set; }
        }

        public class AccountDetails
        {
            [XmlAttribute("FCName")]
            public string FCName { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("TariffName")]
            public string TariffName { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Area")]
            public int Area { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("SLDG")]
            public int SLDG { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("SLEB")]
            public int SLEB { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("ToDate")]
            public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("FromDate")]
            public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("Address")]
            public string Address { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("MeterNumber")]
            public string MeterNumber { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute("ConsumerName")]
            public string ConsumerName { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, first steps for *deserializing* this xml into C# object is reading about [xml serialization/deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) and trying to write some code. I suggest you to start from these steps

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one parse XML files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy well there is problem for parsing datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` internally uses `XmlConvert` for converting strings to required types. [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) converts strings to dates, but it requires date to be in `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz"` format or its subsets. So, there is no way for you to convert `"12/31/2013"` into `DateTime` with serializer. Workaround is manually parsing your date string:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("ToDate")]
public string ToDateString 
{
    get { return ToDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }
    set { ToDate = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```

Alternative solution (if possible) - changing date format in your xml file to `"2013-01-12"`.