# How can i get data from XML Tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This XML file was obtained using the [Wikipedia API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&search=India)?

```
<SearchSuggestion version="2.0" xmlns="http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2">
    <Query xml:space="preserve">India</Query>
    <Section>
        <Item>
            <Image source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg/50px-Flag_of_India.svg.png" width="50" height="33" />
            <Text xml:space="preserve">India</Text>
            <Description xml:space="preserve">India (), officially the Republic of India ('), is a country in South Asia. It is the seventh-largest country by area, the second-most populous country with over 1.2 billion people, and the most populous democracy in the world. </Description>
            <Url xml:space="preserve">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India</Url>
        </Item>
    </Section>
</SearchSuggestion>
```

I have tried this:

```
var texts = doc.Descendants("Text");
foreach (var text in texts)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(text.Value);
}
```

But I got an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. Then i tried this:

```
XNamespace aw = "https://www.google.org";
IEnumerable<XElement> de =  from el in doc.Descendants(aw + "Text")
                            select el;
foreach (XElement el in de)
    Console.WriteLine(el.Name);
```

but this code gives me a `System.NullReferenceException;Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one parse XML files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

Comment: Based on amount of sample code provided you need basic help on reading XML - check out duplicate question and see if it lets you move forward with your project.

Comment: If you select `Descendants` in Visual Studio and click "F1" you'll get to help article that explain the issue. Here is direct link if you can't find it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your namespace is wrong. Using [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) you can take the default document namespace and then extract the nodes by tag name in this case `Text`:

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlSource); // or XDocument.Load("c:\path\input.xml");
var ns = xml.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var textNodes = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Text").ToList();
foreach (var textNode in textNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(textNode.Value);
}
```

Output in this case is:

> India