# Parsing XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read and get all the customer ids from the xml. i tried the below code. but returns only one id. i have mentioned by xml file as well. Can anyone help on this issue.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\reply2.xml");
            var entries = xdoc.Descendants("customerlist").Select(x => new { custid = (int) x.Element("customerid")});
            foreach (var e in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}", e.custid);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**xml file.**

```
<customerlist>
<customerid>1001</customerid>
<customerid>1002</customerid>
<customerid>1003</customerid>
<customerid>1004</customerid>
</customerlist>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one parse XML files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working, because you are selecting all `customerlist` from your file (there is only one such element, which is root), and then you are projecting *each* `customerlist` element in result sequence to following anonymous type:

```
new { custid = (int)x.Element("customerid")}
```

What is happening here? You gen first `customerid` element from `x` (which is `customerlist`) and return new anonymous object for each `customerlist` item in source sequence. But you have only one `customerlist`. So you have single anonymous object as query result.

If you want to select anonymous type with property `custid`:

```
var entries = from c in xdoc.Root.Elements("customerid")
              select new { custid = (int)c };
```

But I think you can simply select sequence of ids here without creating new type:

```
var ids = xdoc.Root.Elements("customerid").Select(c => (int)c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to do this:

```
List <string> customerId = new List< string>();
string xmlString = @"Your XML string";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

foreach (var element in xDoc.Descendants("customerid"))
{
    customerId.Add(element.Value);
}
```

Comment: but i have file not xml string

Comment: You can load XML file instead of parse like  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfile.xml");