# C# parsing .XSPF (XML) Playlist

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xspf

i need to get the value of the "title"(the folder) attribute
and all "tid"(the id) numbers in every title in the playlist(s)
here is the .xspf

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
        <title>Playlist</title>
        <trackList>
            <track>
                <location>file:///E:/Downloads/video1.mp4</location>
                <duration>681493</duration>
                <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                    <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>
                </extension>
            </track>
            <track>
                <location>file:///E:/Downloads/video2.mp4</location>
                <duration>614585</duration>
                <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                    <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
                </extension>
            </track>
            <track>
                <location>file:///E:/Downloads/video3.mp4</location>
                <duration>220629</duration>
                <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                    <vlc:id>2</vlc:id>
                </extension>
            </track>        
        </trackList>
        <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <vlc:node title="oooh11111.xspf" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/">
        <vlc:node title="BillyJ">
            <vlc:item tid="0" />
            <vlc:item tid="1" />
            <vlc:item tid="2" />
            <vlc:item tid="3" />
            <vlc:item tid="4" />
            <vlc:item tid="5" />
            <vlc:item tid="6" />
            <vlc:item tid="7" />
            <vlc:item tid="8" />
            <vlc:item tid="9" />
            <vlc:item tid="10" />
            <vlc:item tid="57" />
            <vlc:item tid="58" />
            <vlc:item tid="59" />
        </vlc:node>
        <vlc:node title="Solo">
            <vlc:item tid="60" />
            <vlc:item tid="61" />
            <vlc:item tid="62" />
            <vlc:item tid="63" />
            <vlc:item tid="64" />
            <vlc:item tid="65" />
            <vlc:item tid="66" />
            <vlc:item tid="67" />
            <vlc:item tid="102" />
            <vlc:item tid="103" />
            <vlc:item tid="104" />
        </vlc:node>
        <vlc:node title="Best">
            <vlc:item tid="105" />
            <vlc:item tid="106" />
            <vlc:item tid="107" />
            <vlc:item tid="108" />
            <vlc:item tid="109" />
            <vlc:item tid="110" />
            <vlc:item tid="111" />
        </vlc:node>
</extension>
</playlist>
```

but now i need to get the value of the "title"(the folder) attribute
and all "tid"(the id) numbers in every title :
BillyJ
 0
 1
2
3
4
5
...

Solo
60
61
62
63
64
...

So i can sort files to folders by their ids

here is how i parse the location duration and id :

```
        class PlaylistItem
        {
            public string location { get; set; }
            public string extensions { get; set; }
            public string duration { get; set; }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"1.xspf");
            XNamespace ns = ((XElement)xdoc.FirstNode).Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace nx = ("http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/");

            List<PlaylistItem> fileSignatures = (from file in xdoc.Descendants(ns+ "track")
                                                  select new PlaylistItem
                                                  {
                                                      location = (string)file.Element(ns + "location").Value,
                                                      extensions = (string)file.Element(ns + "extension").Value,
                                                      duration = (string)file.Element(ns + "duration")
                                                  }).ToList();


            foreach (var item in fileSignatures)
            {
                if (item.duration != null)
                {
                  //Remove %20 (spaces)
                  var file = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(item.location);
                  //trim file:/// from start
                  char[] trimChar = { 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e','/',':' };
                  file = file.TrimStart(trimChar);
                  listBox1.Items.Add("Duration: " + item.duration + "  id: " + item.extensions);
                  listBox1.Items.Add("File: " + file);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files there are actually a ton of different examples and technologies to do this with do a simple google search if this posting does not provide adequate needs

Comment: yes i know and i have checked lots of places but i havent found how to parse the second part of the file because its in a format i guess isnt much used in xml :

Comment: <vlc:node title="oooh11111.xspf" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/">
        <vlc:node title="BillyJ">
            <vlc:item tid="0" />
            <vlc:item tid="1" />
            <vlc:item tid="2" />
            <vlc:item tid="3" />
            <vlc:item tid="4" />
            <vlc:item tid="5" />
            <vlc:item tid="6" />
            <vlc:item tid="7" />
            <vlc:item tid="8" />
            <vlc:item tid="9" />
            <vlc:item tid="10" />
        </vlc:node>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  You have two tags with 'node' and only one closing tag.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement playlist = (XElement)xdoc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = playlist.Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace nx = ("http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/");

            XElement extension = playlist.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "extension").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace nsExtension = extension.Name.Namespace;
            XElement node = extension.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "node").FirstOrDefault();

            var nodes = node.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "node").Select(y => new {
                title = y.Attribute("title").Value,
                                ids = y.Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute("tid") != null).Select(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("tid").Value)).ToList()

        }
```

Comment: i think its a mistake i didnt wanna put the whole .xspf sinces its over 2000 lines so i shortened it and i think i for got one closing tag. but the orginal file has right number od closing tags. sorry

Comment: i get a NullRefrenceException here: int.Parse(x.Attribute("tid").Value

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: works if i remove ids = y.Elements().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("tid").Value)).ToList()

Comment: You must have a node tag without the attribute "title".  Made one line change to code.

Comment: Thanks alot JDWENG i was getting abit frustrated with it :) *cheer*