# Prolog rule in XML to C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, parsing, prolog

I've defined some facts and a rule in a XML file according to the Prolog language, but now I have to parse it to C# (to have, for example, a button in the c# interface and when you click the button, it will show you the result of the interogation). The problem is that I don't know how to parse the interogation/rule...

Here is the XML code (I hope it's ok the way I've written it - I'm new...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ELEMENT root (Persoane*, Rules)>
  <!ELEMENT Persoane (nume)>
  <!ELEMENT IsMale (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Varsta (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT PersoanaPlacuta (#PCDATA)>
 ]>
<root>
  <Persoane nume ="Bob">
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>30</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Iulia"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane nume ="Bogdan">
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>28</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Ana"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane nume="Mihai">
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>20</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Sofia"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane nume ="Catalin">
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>38</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Iulia"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane nume ="Iulia">
    <IsMale>false</IsMale>
    <Varsta>32</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Bob"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane nume ="Ana">
    <IsMale>false</IsMale>
    <Varsta>27</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Bogdan"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Persoane nume ="Sofia">
    <IsMale>false</IsMale>
    <Varsta>29</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Bob"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>

  <Rules>
    <Rule1>
      <if>
        <Conditions>
          <Condition1>
            <Nume>"X"</Nume>
            <PersoanaPlacuta>"Y"</PersoanaPlacuta>
          </Condition1>
          <Condition2>
            <Nume>"X"</Nume>
            <PersoanaPlacuta>"Y"</PersoanaPlacuta>
          </Condition2>
        </Conditions>
      </if>
      <then>
        <Result>
          <Nume>"X"</Nume>
          <PersoanaPlacuta>"Y"</PersoanaPlacuta>
        </Result>
      </then>
    </Rule1>
  </Rules> 
</root>
```

Comment: There is a very similar question to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810725/parsing-xml-data-in-c-sharp-and-show-into-listbox/34813172#34813172

Comment: I've posted that question, I know... I have no problems showing the data now in a ListBox, but I don't know how to interrogate the rule to give me the answer....

Comment: Which one run the query ? Prolog or C# ? And what about the case mismatch (Nume vs "nume") ? and about useless quoting of literals (`<PersoanaPlacuta>"Iulia"</PersoanaPlacuta>` should be `<PersoanaPlacuta>Iulia</PersoanaPlacuta>` ) ?