# How to replace value in XMLColumn in SQL tabel

Tags: sql, xml

I have this XML where i want to change the value of 97 in the node 'txtqtyremaining' into a new value. How should i do that?

I don't know how to select to correct node and how to change that value.`

```
    <genxml>
  <files />
  <hidden />
  <textbox>
    <txtproductref>SKU</txtproductref>
  </textbox>
  <dropdownlist />
  <checkboxlist />
  <radiobuttonlist />
  <models>
    <genxml>
      <files />
      <textbox>
        <availabledate datatype="date" />
        <txtbarcode>BAR1234</txtbarcode>
        <txtqtyremaining datatype="double">97</txtqtyremaining>
      </textbox>
```

Comment: are you using SQL Server?

Comment: "I don't know how to select to correct node "  Does this mean that path is unknown or variable?

Comment: I'm using SQL server. And i want to know the correct UPDATE statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one parse XML files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/genxml/models/genxml/textbox/txtqtyremaining[1]/text())[1] with "999.99"') 
Select @XML
```

Or you can use a simple Replace()

```
Set @XML = Replace(cast(@XML as varchar(max)),'>97</txtqtyremaining>','>999.999</txtqtyremaining>')
Select @XML
```

Both would Return

```
<genxml>
  <files />
  <hidden />
  <textbox>
    <txtproductref>SKU</txtproductref>
  </textbox>
  <dropdownlist />
  <checkboxlist />
  <radiobuttonlist />
  <models>
    <genxml>
      <files />
      <textbox>
        <availabledate datatype="date" />
        <txtbarcode>BAR1234</txtbarcode>
        <txtqtyremaining datatype="double">999.999</txtqtyremaining>
      </textbox>
    </genxml>
  </models>
</genxml>
```