# Get Markupextension expression in wpf via reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection, markup-extensions

I try to parse WPF Custom Control with LogicalTreeHelper. The LogicalTreeHelper gives me each control as DependancyObject. And I need to investigate which static resources be used with a control.

The Example of an xaml:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{StaticResource MarginExtraSmall}"
       VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.Type}" ></Label>
```

The problem is, when I try to get a value of the "Content" property of the Control "Label", I recieve a string, but I need a markupextension expression insteed, in this case "{x:Static p:Resources.Type}"

Code:

```
DumpElement(object elem)
{
    var dependencyProperties = elem.GetType().GetDependencyProperties();
    DependencyObject dependencyObject = elem as DependencyObject;

    foreach (var dependencyProperty in dependencyProperties)
    {
      var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(dependencyObject, 
      dependencyProperty);
    }

    var publicProperties = elem.GetType().GetPublicProperies();

    foreach (var property in publicProperties)
    {
      var value = property.GetValue(elem);
    }
}
```

Have anybody an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to "parse a XAML file with LogicalTreeHelper". Why don't you use `XamlReader`?

Comment: I want to process the task with reflection and not as text(xml), it is much easier

Comment: What is *"parse WPF Custom Control"*? What do you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: ok, i changed "parse xaml" to "parse WPF Custom Control"

Comment: Sinatr: I must to find all Child controls, check if all controls belong a certain library, save for each control "Bindings" and "Markupextensions"

Comment: Sounds like you simply want to [parse xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55828/1997232). Xaml is xml.

Comment: Sinatr : No, I want to parse a Custom WPF control as object

Comment: Can you put your related code behind?

Comment: I have put the Code up. So threre is no Problem to get binding of a property, but threre is a problem to get Markupextension expression via reflection. property.GetValue(elem) give a resource value(a string), but not an expression