# How do I desirialize this xml document using C# ,I am only interested in the ComplianceInfo part?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How do i parse this xml document using C# ,I am only interested in the ComplianceInfo part?

```
<RootDTO>      
       <SbisInfo>
          <Errors />
          <InfoMessages>
             <InfoMessageDTO>
                <Message>Service completed successfully</Message>
             </InfoMessageDTO>
          </InfoMessages>
          <Customer>
             <BPID>150242138</BPID>
             <ComplianceInfo>
                <ComplianceStatusCode>007</ComplianceStatusCode>
                <ComplianceStatusInd>Y</ComplianceStatusInd>
                <FraudConsentGivenInd>Y</FraudConsentGivenInd>
                <UndesirableStatusCode>009</UndesirableStatusCode>
                <PepStatusCode>007</PepStatusCode>
                <KycStatusCode>001</KycStatusCode>
                <CraStatusCode>004</CraStatusCode>
             </ComplianceInfo>
          </Customer>
       </SbisInfo>
     </RootDTO>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one parse XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828/how-does-one-parse-xml-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data from `ComplianceInfo` node using `XmlDocument` and an XPath selector as follows:

```
string xml = @"your-xml-here";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/RootDTO/SbisInfo/Customer/ComplianceInfo");

string ComplianceStatusCode = node["ComplianceStatusCode"].InnerText;
string ComplianceStatusInd = node["ComplianceStatusInd"].InnerText;
string FraudConsentGivenInd = node["FraudConsentGivenInd"].InnerText;
string UndesirableStatusCode = node["UndesirableStatusCode"].InnerText;
string PepStatusCode = node["PepStatusCode"].InnerText;
string KycStatusCode = node["KycStatusCode"].InnerText;
string CraStatusCode = node["CraStatusCode"].InnerText;
```